# How to turn this into a Python Datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I need a Python Datetime in a yyyy-mm-dd format, but don't really know the best way to take something like this "Tuesday July 7, 2015" and turn it into that.

I'm assuming I would have to extract out the text for the day of the week, which is a pain because it can be any day of the week, once, i Have the rest of the format I could probably use Python built in Datetime to turn it from a string to a datetime object, but my question is, is this the best way?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime

Comment: do you need a datetime object or just a string with the yyyy-mm-dd format?

Comment: just the yyyy-mm-dd format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("Tuesday July 7, 2015", "%A %B %d, %Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

#### The output

http://testedanswers.com/questions/-JsXzg2WOR2IXFRqwT1Q

Answer (score 3):

Here's a overview of the format codes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

> The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms, because Python calls the platform C library’s strftime() function, and platform variations are common. To see the full set of format codes supported on your platform, consult the strftime(3) documentation.

But your example should be parseable with `%A %B %d, %Y`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("Tuesday July 7, 2015", "%A %B %d, %Y")
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 7, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have both the %A and %d format specifiers in the same format string with [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("Tuesday July 7, 2015", "%A %B %d, %Y").date()
datetime.date(2015, 7, 7)
```